# как мне указать на кнопку ВЫХОД которая находится на сайте mail.ru

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    i: integer;
    s:string;
    html_tag:variant;
begin
    html_tag:=webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.item(0).elements;
    for i:=0 to (html_tag.length-1)do
    begin
        if (html_tag.item(i).title='выход') then
        html_tag.item(i).click;
    end;
end;
```

вместо title='выход' не знаю что надо написать.
по нажатию на Button6 должен произойти выход и почты, я не могу найти адресс как обратится к 'выходу'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399284/how-to-click-button-class-webbrowser-delphi `innerText` пишите

Comment: innerText='выход' так чтоли?

Comment: я не в курсе, какой именно элемент вы пытаетесь нажать. если это `<button>выход</button>` то видимо так.

Comment: там нету элемента button

Comment: дак приведите код формы тогда. телепаты тут отсутствуют